# How to remove an item in list once used from a large list in python to save the memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, memory-management

If i have large list which runs in millions of items, i want to iterate through each of them. Once i use the item it will never be used again, so how do i delete the item from the list once used? What is the best approach?
I know numpy is fast and efficient but want to know how it can be done using normal list.

```
mylst = [item1, item2,............millions of items]
for each_item in mylist:
    #use the item
    #delete the item to free that memory
```

Comment: The entire list will be garbage collected after you are done and you are not using the list after that, why do you need to remove items individually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete an object directly in Python - an object's memory is automatically reclaimed, by garbage collection, when it's no longer possible to reference the object.  So long as an object *is* in a list, it may be referenced again later (via the list).

So you need to destroy the list too.  For example, like so:

```
while mylst:
    each_item = mylst.pop()  # removes an object from the end of the list
    # use the item
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can copy a list (memory constraints might cause issues here) and only need to remove specific elements from it, you can create a shallow copy of the list and remove elements from it while iterating through the original list:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b_list = a_list.copy()
removal_key = 0
for element in a_list:
    if element % 2 == 0:
        b_list.pop(removal_key)
        removal_key -= 1; # we need to push the removal key back afer every deletion as our array b_list becomes smaller than the original after every deletion
    removal_key += 1
print(b_list) #[1, 3, 5]
```

If creating the 2nd list is not an option, you can store the key's of elements to be removed from the list and then use a second list to remove them :

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
elements_to_remove = []
for key, element in enumerate(a_list):
    if element % 2 == 0:
        elements_to_remove.append(key)

removed_emelent_count = 0
for element in elements_to_remove:
    a_list.pop(element - removed_emelent_count)
    removed_emelent_count += 1
print(a_list) #[1, 3, 5]
```

Note that the 1st solution is more time efficient (especially when removing a lot of elements) while the 2nd solution is more memory efficient, especially when removing smal number of elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the case in which you should use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

A generator is a function that returns an object which we can iterate over, one value at a time, using the special keyword `yield` instead of `return`.
They allows you to have a smaller memory footprint, by keeping only one element per iteration.

In python3.x, `range` is actually a generator (python2.x is `xrange`).

Overly simple example:

```
>>> def range(start, end):
...     current = start
...     while current < end:
...         yield current
...         current += 1
...
>>> for i in range(0, 2):
...     print(i)
...
0
1
```

How is this million entries list made?